# How to enable the FinderSync in code

Tags: macos, finder-extension

I enable the FinderSync in my Host app with the method introduced by : [How to enable FinderSync Extension in the System Preference in Cocoa - Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176942/how-to-enable-findersync-extension-in-the-system-preference-in-cocoaSystem) Preference-objective 
The extension is added in the System Preference but not checked , sometimes is checked.
So any body can help me, Any help is appreciated!

My OSx is 10.11.5, and the Xcode is 7.3.1.

Comment: When i debug the "system()", I see nothing in  my console. It is only check the system preference when first launch the extension app.

Answer (score 2):

I add the FinderSync extension name to the bundle ID, it works.

```
system("pluginkit -e use -i mybundleID.FinderSyncExtensionName");
```