# how to make a finder sync extension load automatically?

Tags: cocoa, findersync

i create a cocoa application project, and add target "Finder sync extension". Then the "finderSync.appex" will be put to ".../Contens/Plugins/" folder. But when i launch the application, the extension is not loaded automatically, should i load it manually ? How can i load it ?

From the Apple developement guide, it says:

```
For OS X to recognize and automatically load the Finder Sync extension, the extension target’s info.plist file must contain the following entries:

<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.FinderSync</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).FinderSync</string>
</dict>
```

I already set as the above, but it doens't work.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Could you resolve this. 

On adding $PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME the app crashes.

Manually it can be done in this fashion, but i am not sure if this is how it is supposed to be done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176942/how-to-enable-findersync-extension-in-the-system-preference-in-cocoa-objective

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your extension with Finder:

```
pluginkit -a <path you your appex>
```

You might also need to tell Finder to enable your extension:

```
pluginkit -e use -i <ID of you appex>
```

Comment: Looks like that should be a lowercase "I": "pluginkit -e use -i <ID>" (possibly you were hacked by auto-correct, as I was just now).

Comment: @rsfinn Thank you