# How to launch app's FinderSync Extension from code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, findersync

I've made finder sync extension using [instruction](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH15-SW1).

It displays in finder when I launch it directly from Xcode. But it is not visible when I run the main app. Is there some way to do it for sandbox app? In not sandboxed app I used the code:

```
NSTask *fseEnable = [[NSTask alloc] init];
fseEnable.launchPath = @"/usr/bin/pluginkit";
fseEnable.arguments = @[@"-e", @"use", @"-i", @"com.team.AppName.FinderSyncExtension"];

[fseEnable launch];
```

But it does not work for sandboxed. I tried:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.team.AppName.FinderSyncExtension" options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault additionalEventParamDescriptor:nil launchIdentifier:nil];
```

But It also did not work.

Probably there is some checkbox in project settings to do it. but I haven't fond it.

Also I've found probably sad news in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1).

> After installing an app extension, a user must take action to enable
>   it. Often, users can enable an extension within the context of their
>   current task. If your extension is a Today widget, for example, users
>   can edit the Today view in Notification Center to enable your
>   extension. In other cases, users can use Settings (in iOS) or System
>   Preferences (in macOS) to enable and manage the extensions they
>   install.

Answer (score -1):

Use `int system(const char *)` instead of `NSTask`.

```
system("pluginkit -e use -i com.team.AppName.FinderSyncExtension");
```