# Finder Sync/Overlays Extension not launching

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plugins, findersync

I am facing an issue where finder overlays sync icons are not shown.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
NSString* bundleID = @"com.my.myapp"; 
NSString* extBundleID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.finderoverlays", bundleID];
NSString* runCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pluginkit -e use -i %@", extBundleID];

NSLog(@"runcommand= %s", runCommand.UTF8String);

int result = system(runCommand.UTF8String);

NSLog(@"setting up finder overlays, returned = %d", result);
```

The result is always 0, but the extension is not shown on the SystemPreference's extension tab.
When I run the project, directly using Xcode then the extension is shown in System Preferences.

What am I missing here?

Do I need to keep the `appex` file somewhere at a specific location?

Comment: Why are you using the Swift tag when your code is clearly Objective-C only? Please don't spam tags.

Comment: Check plugin status using "pluginkit -m -i om.my.myapp.finderoverlays" command